# How to use pattern matching within curried function

Tags: f#

I'm learning F# and I'm trying the following exercise (exercise 4.10 of [Functional Programming Using F#](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107684064)).

> Declare an F# function `prefix`: `'a list -> 'a list -> bool when a:equality`. The value of the expression `prefix[x_0;x_1;...;x_m] [y_0;y_1;...;y_n]` is `true` if `m<=n` and `x_i=y_i` for `0<=i<=m`, and `false` otherwise.

I wanted to use pattern matching on the two inputs, but wasn't sure how to do this with a curried function (as opposed to a function taking a 2-tuple). So I wrote:

```
let rec prefix a b = (function
    | ([], _) -> true
    | (_, []) -> false
    | (x0::xst,y0::yst) -> x0 = y0 && prefix xst yst) (a,b);;
```

I wasn't very happy with this, because I thought it would be better (clearer and more efficient) if the inner function called itself, so I tried declaring the inner function locally.

```
let prefix a b =
    let rec prefixt = function
        | ([], _) -> true
        | (_, []) -> false
        | (x0::xst,y0::yst) -> x0 = y0 && prefixt (xst,yst)
    prefixt (a,b);;
```

Is this the right way to approach such a problem in F#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `match … with …` syntax:

```
let rec prefix a b =
    match (a, b) with
    | ([], _) -> true
    | (_, []) -> false
    | (x0::xst,y0::yst) -> x0 = y0 && prefix xst yst
```